# @import url doesn't work with gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: compilation, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to compile my scss in a css file. 
Everything is working except this :

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,600,700');

In my css, I've got the same thing :

```
   @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300");
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%} ......
```

Here my gulp task :

```
  return sass(vendorFiles.scss.app, {
        compass: true,
        style: 'compressed'
    })
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(rename('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distPaths.css));
});
```

I tried without quotes, without url, none of this worked.
Others imports work but when I try with @import url, with any url, it doesn't matter, it wont work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by it won't work?  Do you get a sass error?

Try https --- note the "s"

Is it the first line of your css?

Where and how do you use Roboto - I see no reference to it?

Comment: I've got no error in sass. In my css (compiled) I get the same line, no transformation or error, just  @import url(...). I tried "http" and https same result. I've tried multiple url (like material icons) and i have the same result. It can be my first line of css, if I write it in first in my app.scss but the problem is the same if I put it in the end, middle or anywhere :/

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use `@import` in as it can cause render block issues, and i did tried the @import in VSCode with sass-lint. They showed an error.

[image: @import error]

I would suggest using in this way :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700"   rel="stylesheet">
```

Problem: This method of calling CSS is bad because it adds to the time that it takes to load your css before your page can load.

Solution: Locate the @ import calls and replace them.

Detection: Use the pagespeed tool. In the left hand column one of the items is "Avoid @ CSS import". If you have a green checkmark, no @imports were found. If found, there will be a red "x".

Details: CSS imports look like this and will usually be near the top of the file.

```
@import url("style.css")
```

Rather than call that css file using the import method it is better to just keep that additional css in just one file (copy and paste the imported css into the original css file).

For more info: Go through this link. [Dont use @import](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking-css.html)

Comment: That's a great answer, but not for my problem ^^ When I compile my .scss in one file .css, import url doesn't work for url. The compilation is done only one time on your server, so no render block issues. But thanks for the answer !